# Two background manager page use a little different base template

Tags: django, django-templates

There are two user background manager page, one for staff to manage order, enterprise. one for normaluser to manage themself order or user center. So there are two url path: /staff_bg/  /user_bg/
But they are use the same base template, the only different is the header tabs is not same. For example:

user_header.html

```
{% extends "core/base.html" %}
<header>
    <ul>
        <li>your orders</li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

staff_header.html

```
{% extends "core/base.html" %}
<header>
    <ul>
        <li>enterprise</li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

then:
user_realted.html:

```
{% extends "core/user_header.html" %}  # focus here
{% block body %} 
# something
{% endblock %}
```

then:
staff_related.html

```
{% extends "core/staff_header.html" %} # focus here
{% block body %} 
# something
{% endblock %}
```

my solution:
create core/middle.html:

```
{% extends the_template_name %}
```

then 
user_realted.html:

```
{% extends "core/middle.html" %}  # focus here
{% block body %} 
# something
{% endblock %}
```

One way write custom template processor, base one request.path pass different the_template_name( "cms/user_header.html" or "core/staff_header.html" ) to middle.html, but I think it's dirty,
and if code wrong, maybe normal user can see the staff tabs.

another way: 
pass different the_template_name to middle.html, in every view. of course, it will change every view that already wrote.

Comment: I use  templateView solve it, pass different the_template_name to every view. of course according DRY, use base view is good choice.